# Dynamic script inventory of the EC2 instances with Tag name Ansible basing on its values

Tags: python, boto3

I am trying to write a sample python code using Boto3 function, to check Ec2 instances with Tag Name'Ansible' and its value 'DB' or 'APP' it should return the respective Private IP addresses of these Tag values.

tried to change filter by adding [].
In the code i found in youtube links, there are no [] even after adding them i am getting this error.

```
#!/bin/python
import boto3
import json
def get_hosts(ec2,fv):
        f=[{'Name':'tag:Ansible','values':[fv]}]
        hosts=[]
        for each_in in ec2.instances.filter(Filters=[f]):
                print each_in.private_ip_address
                hosts.append(each_in.private_ip_address)
        return hosts

def main():
        ec2=boto3.resource("ec2")
        db_group = get_hosts(ec2,"db")
        app_group = get_hosts(ec2,"app")


if __name__ =="__main__":
        main()
```

For example, i have 4 instances with Tag name Ansible has values like 'db' as 2 instances and 'app' another 2 instances.
My output should be like
db [172.31.24.232,172.31.21.244]
app [172.31.30.42,172.31.26.116]

Answer (score 0):

```
Below is the correct code and usage of filters.

#!/bin/python
import boto3
import json
def get_hosts(ec2,fv):
        #f=[{'Name':'tag:Ansible','values':[fv]}]
        hosts = []
        #for each_in in ec2.instances.filter[Filters=[f]]:
        #for each_in in ec2.describe_instances(Filters=[{'Name':'tag:Ansible','Values':[fv]}]):
        instances = ec2.instances.filter(Filters=[{'Name': 'tag:Ansible', 'Values': [fv]}])
        for instance in instances:
                #print instance.private_ip_address
                hosts.append(instance.private_ip_address)
        return hosts

def main():
        ec2=boto3.resource("ec2")
        db_group = get_hosts(ec2,"db")
        app_group = get_hosts(ec2,"app")
        print "db :", db_group
        print "app :",app_group

if __name__ =="__main__":
        main()
```